# How to find the positions of a list of certain number in a number list

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I have a list of number: `[0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]`, which is composed of either 0 or 1,and my problem is how to find the beginning and ending positions of the number `1` in the list. Take the above list of number as an example, and the positions of a list of `1` are:

```
[2 4]
[6 7]
[9 9]
[13 14]
```

Using C++, the following method is implemented:

```
int main()
{   

    unsigned char charArray[15]={0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > posArray;

    int begPos=-1;
    int endPos=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        if(charArray[i] ==1)
        {
            if(begPos!=-1)
            {
                endPos++;
            }
            else
            {
                begPos=i;
                endPos=i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(begPos != -1)
            {
                posArray.push_back(std::make_pair<int,int>(begPos,endPos));
                begPos=-1;
            }

        }

    }
    if(charArray[14] == 1)
    {
        posArray.push_back(std::make_pair<int,int>(begPos,endPos));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<posArray.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"( "<<posArray[i].first<<" , "<<posArray[i].second<<" )"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are there more efficient solutions (either in time or in space) to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If it works, then what would be better?

Comment: In other words, you're going to have to tell us what "better" means to you, or you'll just get a bunch of input based on what someone else's interpretation of "better" is based on their own biases.

Comment: May be [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) would be more suitable to handle this, but looking up the positions may not change very much.

Comment: @JohnDibling Here, I am interested in all the possible solutions to this problem. The best one would be the most efficient one.

Comment: I don't think you can do it better than `O(n)`

Comment: More efficient as in with time or with space?

Comment: Better & more efficient? sure. Make it a template function that outputs an iterator class which stores the current position as an iterator and uses `std::find` instead of manually searching. For some non-vector containers, this could be less than `O(lgn)` (`std::set` would be O(n) since it will only have 1 partition), and compared to yours it'll not be `O(n)` in space.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Thanks for the comments, but I am not sure that I understand you. Could you write some codes to demonstrate your solutions? Thanks.

Comment: @feelfree nope. You'll have to look into custom iterators yourself, and I must stress that the improvements of this are TINY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I will suggest is not more efficient but looks better.:)

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char charArray[] = 
    { 
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
    };
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > posArray;

    auto first = std::begin( charArray );

    while ( ( first = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 1 ) ) != std::end( charArray) )
    {
        auto last = std::find_if( first, std::end( charArray ), 
                                  std::bind2nd( std::not_equal_to<int>(), 1 ) );

        posArray.push_back( { std::distance( charArray, first ),
                              std::distance( charArray, last ) - 1 } );
        first = last;                             
    }

    for ( auto &p : posArray ) std::cout << '[' << p.first 
                                         << ' ' << p.second
                                         << ']' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
[2 4]
[6 7]
[9 9]
[13 14]
```

If the array consists only from 0 and 1 then you may substitute this statement

```
    auto last = std::find_if( first, std::end( charArray ), 
                              std::bind2nd( std::not_equal_to<int>(), 1 ) );
```

for this one

```
    auto last = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 0 );
```

In this case the loop will look like

```
while ( ( first = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 1 ) ) != std::end( charArray) )
{
    auto last = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 0 ); 

    posArray.push_back( { std::distance( charArray, first ),
                          std::distance( charArray, last ) - 1 } );
    first = last;                             
}
```

To write a more efficient code you have to reserve memory for the vector.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char charArray[] = 
    { 
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
    };
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > posArray;

    size_t n = std::inner_product( std::next( std::begin( charArray ) ), 
                                   std::end( charArray ), 
                                   std::begin( charArray ), 
                                   0ul, 
                                   std::plus<size_t>(),
                                   std::greater<char>() );

   n += charArray[0] == 1;

    posArray.reserve( n );

    auto first = std::begin( charArray );

    while ( ( first = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 1 ) ) != std::end( charArray) )
    {
        auto last = std::find( first, std::end( charArray ), 0 ); 

        posArray.push_back( { std::distance( charArray, first ),
                              std::distance( charArray, last ) - 1 } );
        first = last;                             
    }

    for ( auto &p : posArray ) std::cout << '[' << p.first 
                                         << ' ' << p.second
                                         << ']' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist. Here is my two-penneth:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char charArray[] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > posArray;

    size_t found[2];
    unsigned char seek = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(charArray); ++i)
    {
        if(seek == charArray[i])
            continue;

        found[seek] = i - seek;

        if(!(seek ^= 1))
            posArray.push_back(std::make_pair(found[0], found[1]));
    }

    if(seek)
        posArray.push_back(std::make_pair(found[0], sizeof(charArray) - 1));

    for(int i = 0; i < posArray.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "[" << posArray[i].first
            << " , " << posArray[i].second << "]" << '\n';
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2 , 4]
[6 , 7]
[9 , 9]
[13 , 14]
```